# Generate a Word document in JavaScript with Docx.js?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, docx

I am trying to use [docx.js](https://raw.github.com/stephen-hardy/DOCX.js/master/docx.js) to generate a Word document but I can't seem to get it to work.

I copied the raw code into the Google Chrome console after amending line 247 to fix a "'textAlign' undefined error"

```
if (inNode.style && inNode.style.textAlign){..}
```

Which makes the function `convertContent` available. The result of which is an Object e.g.

```
JSON.stringify( convertContent($('<p>Word!</p>)[0]) )
```

Results in -

```
"{"string":
      "<w:body>
            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t xml:space=\"preserve\">Word!</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
       </w:body>"
 ,"charSpaceCount":5
 ,"charCount":5,
 "pCount":1}"
```

I copied

```
<w:body>
    <w:p>
        <w:r>
            <w:t xml:space="preserve">Word!</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
</w:body>
```

into Notepad++ and saved it as a file with an extension of 'docx' but when I open it in MS Word but it says 'cannot be opened because there is a problem with the contents'.

Am I missing some attribute or XML tags or something?

Comment: Have you tried using the Github repo of M4rio ? it has one example of use: https://github.com/MrRio/DOCX.js

Comment: After running the example code I am getting this error - `TypeError: Object function bound(var_args) { return func.apply(thisObject, args.concat(slice(arguments))); } has no method 'ajax'`

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery ? Dependencies are the following: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./libs/base64.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./libs/jszip/jszip.js"></script>`

Comment: Yes I did. I am trying to setup a JSFiddle but I am not sure if it is an appropriate environment http://jsfiddle.net/iampeterbanjo/srK2u/6/

Comment: You're right, thing is that the folder `blank` contains the data of an empty document, and the Javascript loads this blank document via `ajax` to create the new document

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code can't work on a JSFiddle because of the ajaxCalls to local files (everything that is in the `blank`folder), or you should enter all files in ByteArray format and use the `jsFiddle` echo API: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html

Comment: Thanks. I have decided to do this server side using a library called https://docx.codeplex.com/ It would have been cool to do it with JavaScript but oh well. :-)

Comment: If you want a javascript only solution to generate docx from docx templates, have a look at the library I created: https://github.com/edi9999/docxgenjs

Comment: wow. that is really cool. can you use base64 images or canvas elements with it? do you have a demo page or hello_word.docx example(s)?

Comment: Sorry, I just found one of your examples - https://github.com/edi9999/docxgenjs/blob/master/examples/textTagging.html

Comment: yep, online examples can be found here: http://javascript-ninja.fr/docxgenjs/examples/simpleTagging.html#

Comment: That is awesome! I would be happy to accept this as an answer if you could post it as one. Thanks.

Comment: These comments relates to my answer (I can put more info on the post if you think it could be useful)

Answer (score 22):

You can generate a Docx Document from a template using [docxtemplater](https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater) (library I have created).

It can replace tags by their values (like a template engine), and also replace images in a paid version.

Here is a demo of the templating engine: https://docxtemplater.com/demo/

Comment: [The module to work with images appears to be paid-only](https://docxtemplater.com/modules/image/)

Comment: the free version already looks great

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an older question and you already have an answer, but I struggled getting this to work for a day, so I thought I'd share my results.

Like you, I had to fix the `textAlign` bug by changing the line to this:

```
if (inNode.style && inNode.style.textAlign)
```

Also, it didn't handle HTML comments. So, I had to add the following line above the check for a "#text" node in the `for` loop:

```
if (inNodeChild.nodeName === '#comment') continue;
```

To create the docx was tricky since there is absolutely no documentation on this thing as of yet. But looking through the code, I see that it is expecting the HTML to be in a File object. For my purposes, I wanted to use the HTML I rendered, not some HTML file the user has to select to upload. So I had to trick it by making my own object with the same property that it was looking for and pass it in. To save it to the client, I use [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/), which requires a blob. I **[included this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)** that converts base64 into a blob. So my code to implement it is this:

```
var result = docx({ DOM: $('#myDiv')[0] });
var blob = b64toBlob(result.base64, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
saveAs(blob, "test.docx");
```

In the end, this would work for simple Word documents, but isn't nearly sophisticated for anything more. I couldn't get any of my styles to render and I didn't even attempt to get images working. I've since abandoned this approach and am now researching [DocxgenJS](https://github.com/edi9999/docxgenjs) or some server-side solution.

Answer (score 2):

You may find this link useful,

> http://evidenceprime.github.io/html-docx-js/

An online demo here:

> http://evidenceprime.github.io/html-docx-js/test/sample.html

Comment: Thank you! I was able to save an image to a docx! I needed to `npm install` the following: `html-docx-js`, `brfs`, `coffeeify`, `coffeescript`, [`file-saver` (for `saveAs`)](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)

Comment: @WordsLikeJared how do you save image without tinymce? I don't think tinymce is needed right?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the correct thing codewise, but your file is not a valid docx file.  If you look through the `docx()` function in docx.js, you will see that a docx file is actually a zip containing several xml files.

Comment: Thanks. How do I convert those zip/xml files into a valid docx format?

Comment: I think you could pass a complete html file to the `docx()` function's file parameter.  It will return the result.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Open Xml SDK for JavaScript.

http://ericwhite.com/blog/open-xml-sdk-for-javascript/

Basically, on web server, I have a empty docx file as new template.
when user in browser click new docx file, I will retrieve the empty docx file as template, convert it to BASE64 and return it as Ajax response.

in client scripts, you convert the BASE64 string to byte array and using openxmlsdk.js to load the byte array as an javascript OpenXmlPackage object.

once you have the package loaded, you can use regular OpenXmlPart to create a real document. (inserting image, creating table/row ).

the last step is stream it out to end user as a document. this part is security related. in my code I send it back to webserver and gets saved temporarily. and prepare a http response to notify end user to download it.

Check the URL above, there are useful samples of doing this in JavaScript.