# How to export image and contents to wordfile using jquery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to export text and image to pdf using client side + server side logic.

For pdf client side

```
$http.get( url, {cache: false} )
            .success( function( data )
            {
                if(success){
                    window.location.href = 'service path';

                }
            })
```

I am able to generate pdf .

But no idea how to export image and content into word file .I have googled but didnt get any answer .I am converting images into binary format.

Is it possible to do in client side .Please suggest

Comment: So you want the user to give input in form of images and content, right? And the user shall receive a Word file in return from the server?

Comment: i have 3 buttons in view ,export to pdf ,print and export to word file .Clicking on export to word file ,i need to open or download wordfile with image and content .Server side i am using asp,

Comment: Try these: https://github.com/edi9999/docxtemplater ; or as well http://blog.innovatejs.com/?p=184 ; taken from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899883/generate-a-word-document-in-javascript-with-docx-js

Comment: That's only for the client side, of course.

Comment: Thank you very much let me try this

Comment: Not sure about IE. Not the safest solution maybe... :(