# How to generate a word document from HTML input fields?

Tags: javascript, html, ms-word

I am a novice HTML/CSS/JS developer. I would like to create a simple web application which will create a word document from the input text fields from the browser(and also a table if possible) and style them in word document. Word document will be pretty straight-forward with 6-7 sections (title and paragraph) and one section with a table(income-expense table). Help would be much appreciated if you can guide me what to search for to accomplish this. I am not expecting a full code or anything, just a guidance.

I tried to google to find a way, but could not manage to find one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using JavaScript to "Create" a Microsoft Word Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779926/using-javascript-to-create-a-microsoft-word-document)

Comment: check this plugin, https://github.com/aadel112/googoose